# jquery visualisation fade and reorder specific images

Tags: jquery, image, fade

I made some renders of a room in different light setups.
Then make 3 buttons to control lights.
The idea is to fade in or fade out a specific image. In that way, I can turn on and off random lights. I have all variations of image.

Press buttons from left to right to see what I mean.

[jsfiddle SCRIPT](http://jsfiddle.net/ponciusz/yF29L)

I was thinking about 3 variables

```
v1,v2,v3
```

and all f this can be "1" or "0" so I can call all variables for example

```
"101"  <- mean that first and last light are on
```

and another problem is reordering the images to put the proper one below the active one.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: since nothing seems to change in demo and all images are stacked it's very hard to tell what behavior you are looking for. I think you need to think differently and hide all but the one you want to show

Comment: Its working i checked it but only if You pres in order v1 v2 v3

Comment: you want toggle variables on each click of that specific buttons right?

Comment: @Ponciusz I don't get which order your images should be but the logic behind code can work out somthing like this. Take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/yF29L/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first thing you have to remember is to `fadeOut` all of your images, then `fadeIn` the one you want as your starting image. Then do the same thing when you click the button. For easier jQuery approach I added a dummy class `active` to your button like this:

```
<a class="sim1 sim-button active" href="#">v1</a>     
<a class="sim2 sim-button active" href="#">v2</a>
<a class="sim3 sim-button active" href="#">v3</a>
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yF29L/12/), then below is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sim-img img").each(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(100);
    });
    var selected_image = ".i111";
    $(selected_image).fadeIn(1000);
    $(".sim-button").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }else{
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
        console.log("prev: "+selected_image);
        $(selected_image).fadeOut(1000);
        selected_image = ".i";
        $(".sim-button").each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("active")){
                selected_image += "1";
            }else{
                selected_image += "0";
            }
        });
        $(selected_image).fadeIn(1000);
        console.log("next: "+selected_image);
    });   
});
```

Comment: Exacly that effect i was wandering 
Thanks very much!
You really help my!

Comment: i need get some reps i am fresh one